# Analog of JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType() for XML data

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, json.net, deserialization

Is there anything similar to [JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType()](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm) but for **XML**? So that I could, for example, write something like this:

```cs
var definition = new
{
    root = new
    {
        id = 0,
        data = "" 
    }
};

string inputXmlString = @"<root><id>345</id><data>Sunday</data></root>";

var obj = SomeXmlConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(inputXmlString , definition);

if (obj.root.id == 345)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: [Convert XML to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertXmlToJson.htm), then convert the JSON to anonymous type?

Comment: The main reason why I have to deal with XML instead of JSON is because of properties like "@version" or "?xml" in JSON output from service - I have no idea how to create anonymous type with them :) The XML output seems more reliable where such properties are just attributes of the node.